# Golang: Convertir un texto plano a un formato CVS o Json para añadirlo a una BD

Tags: go

estoy en una prueba de Truora y me gustaría saber una forma de convetir un texto como este:

> #00005f499a80�b8506811�4.148.158.185�android�(fc5de8c5)��#00005f499a81�fa2b0169�238.67.55.226�android�(d2ed8dcb,3b762217,b7b3ec25,ac7f0bb9,1239369e)

Convertirlo a un formato JSON o CVS, algo que me permita tener una forma de ingresarlo a una BD, y lastimosamente no sé por qué aparecen esos rombos con interrogaciones, el lenguaje que debo utilizar es Golang, muchisimas gracias de verdad si alguien puede ayudarme

Answer (score 1):

Ese texto parece una stream binaria de información, los símbolos de interrogación son caracteres desconocidos. Has probado a abrirlo con un editor hexadecimal? Hay plugins en VS-Code.

Para codificar en CSV o JSON se puede hacer manualmente, pero personalmente te recomiendo usar estructuras propias con las librerías oficiales [JSON](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) y [CSV](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/). En la propia documentación tienes ejemplos de como hacerlo.